# Efficient strategy to split database records into processed/unprocessed

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, partitioning

I often encounter this use case:

I have a queue table with a high number (several millions) of records to process (synchronize with a remote API, ...).

Traditionally I would use the following approach:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Queue (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
    processed TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

And a batch process would look like:

- `SELECT ... FROM Queue WHERE processed = 0 LIMIT n;`
- Perform the task on the records
- `UPDATE Queue SET processed = 1 WHERE id IN(...);`
- Rinse and repeat

When using this approach as is, the `SELECT` potentially yields a full table scan (this may be fast enough for the first batches, but becomes slower and slower as the first records in the table gradually become `processed=1` and the `SELECT` has to read them anyway).

I can only see two options to improve the performance:

### Add an index on the `processed` column

The very low cardinality (`0|1`) of the index will likely not improve the performance at all.

### Partition the table

Partitioning on the `processed` column would make `SELECT` very fast (assuming no `ORDER BY` clause is used) as it could just return the `n` first records in the partition.

The performance penalty comes with the `UPDATE` however, which has to move records from one partition to the other.

---

**Did I miss a better performing approach for this quite common use case?**

Comment: Your `SELECT` would be much quicker if you somehow provided the `id` value where to start looking from. When you process a batch, you can save the last value of auto_increment that you processed. Let's say it's `10000` for example's sake. If your query is `SELECT ... FROM Queue WHERE processed = 0 AND id BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000 LIMIT N` - that's *much* quicker than query you're using. Now, the issues could be gaps in auto increments (you probably won't have a lot in a queue though) etc., but if you only scan 10k records at a time - you should see better performance.

Comment: @Mjh This is an excellent idea, that would deserve an answer on its own! Gaps are a non-issue here as far as I can see: if they do exist, at worst they'll make a batch smaller than expected, which is rarely a problem.

Comment: I posted the answer, it'd be great if you can share if this trick worked for you, I really haven't measured but logically - it should be working really fast :)

Comment: Let me add my 2 cents. The index on the processed flag would do the job alone, without need of partitioning nor selecting a subset of ids; adding the index would let the db engine jump immediately to the first id not processed. I really can't understand your objection about the cardinality

Comment: @perissf - it wouldn't. Indexing columns with 2 possible values does absolutely nothing for performance. His objection is completely and 100% valid.

Answer (score 2):

As per comment: providing the value of primary key can speed up the select significantly. When processing queues using MySQL, it would be good to remember what was the value of last `id` that was processed and save it somewhere. Performing range queries on a primary key column, such as:

```
SELECT ... FROM Queue WHERE id BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000 LIMIT N;
```

produces significantly faster results. I haven't measured anything, but for people using MySQL as a queue mechanism - the above modification of the queue retrieval should yield significant results.

Your mileage my vary depending on gaps between autoincrements etc, so the above approach should be used with care and measurement before implementation.

Comment: How big can be the `id` value? it has some max value limits on increment. Does this not create an issue?

Comment: With this approach, how to handle deletion strategy for processed rows? Because table size grows with processed rows(not required anymore). How should a database trigger  delete the processed records, once in a while?